# windows-xp-sp3 disable DEP but stack still can't execute

Tags: windows, stack, stack-overflow, dep

[image]

I'm trying a simple stack overflow exercise under Windows, but when I turn off DEP protection, the stack area still seems to have no execution permissions?

The coredump shows corrupt at the stack arena, and use the Ollydbg to check, stack not executable also.

How can I make the stack executable on windows xp sp3.